# TableView is blinking on more data append in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, tableview, heightforrowatindexpath

I've involved with TableView Blinking problem. When I appending data in tableview by loadmore, TableView is blinking. If I am using this code then everything fine.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return 400;
}
```

But I am calculating the height of each row. Because each row height is not same. Then I am using that code, after applying that code, My TableView is blinking.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSMutableArray *temp;

if(_buddyWallSection)
    temp =  arrayBuddyList;
else
    temp = arrayMyWallList;

CGFloat height = 320;
if( [[temp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row/2] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] )
{
    return height;
}
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(280,9999);
GolferWall *wallComnt = [temp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row/2];
CGSize expectedSize = [[self plainTextFromHTMLText:wallComnt.contentTextHTML]sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:FontNameArial size:15] constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize  lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
height = expectedSize.height;

NSLog(@"expected size %f", height);

if(wallComnt.imageNames.count == 0)
   return 130 + ( height);

if ( height < 100 )
{
    height = 350;
}
else
    height = height * 2 ;

return height;
}
```

may you please check what I am missing ?

Thank you

Comment: As you can see, that method is called for every row in your uitableview and you are performing a cpu intensive task with:

CGSize expectedSize = [[self plainTextFromHTMLText:wallComnt.contentTextHTML]sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:FontNameArial size:15] constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize  lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

So my advice is to pre-evaluate the size for every row and store that information in an object you can access from tableview:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: Are you by chance implementing the willDisplayCell method?

Comment: @Lolloz89 yes so it is taking time. do we have another way for fixing it?

Comment: @ZeMoon I never used that method "willDisplayCell"

Comment: @Lolloz89 kindly may you please give me hint for  pre-evaluate the size for every row

Comment: @RahulRawat yes, as I said, you can evaluate every height only one time, for example in viewDidLoad. then you store that height in a property of GolferWall as a CGFloat. Or better, you can evaluate that property in the init method of GolferWall.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to write an answer that summarize the comments above, feel free to accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are performing a cpu intensive task every time a row is about to be displayed. More precisely the problem is at the line below:

```
CGSize expectedSize = [[self plainTextFromHTMLText:wallComnt.contentTextHTML]sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:FontNameArial size:15] 
constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize  
lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

The solution is to pre-evaluate that size, once for every object. For example in your GolferWall class you could add a property like this:

```
@property (nonatonic, assign, readonly) CGFloat contentSize;
```

And in the GolferWall init method you can simply copy the code you already wrote in tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (instancetype) init
{
    self = [super init];
    *** your init stuff here ***
    self.contentSize = [[self plainTextFromHTMLText:self.contentTextHTML]sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:FontNameArial size:15] constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize  lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    return self;
}
```

Then in tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: simply replace this code:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSMutableArray *temp;

if(_buddyWallSection)
temp =  arrayBuddyList;
else
    temp = arrayMyWallList;

CGFloat height = 320;
if( [[temp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row/2] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] )
{
    return height;
}
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(280,9999);
GolferWall *wallComnt = [temp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row/2];

// The magic is here
CGSize expectedSize = wallComnt.contentSize;
height = expectedSize.height;

NSLog(@"expected size %f", height);

if(wallComnt.imageNames.count == 0)
   return 130 + ( height);

if ( height < 100 )
{
    height = 350;
}
else
    height = height * 2 ;

return height;
}
```